# Как записать ArrayList в файл и прочитать его обратно?

Tags: android, массивы, json

Есть массив ArrayList(Uri) filesPath , который хочу записать в файл внутренней памяти. 
Я создал JSONArray и записал его в файл:

```
    JSONArray jsFilesPath = new JSONArray(filesPath);
    MyJSON.saveJsData(getApplicationContext(), jsFilesPath, fileNamePath);
```

Метод saveJsData прописан в классе MyJSON, вот его код:

```
public static void saveJsData(Context context, JSONArray jsFilePath, String fileName) {
    try {
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + fileName);
        file.write(String.valueOf(jsFilePath));
        file.flush();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "method saveJsData - File writted ");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error in Writing: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как прочитать теперь этот файл и получить из него массив Uri?

Comment: Попробуйте вот так файловое содержимое в виду строки получить: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13357785/3212712

Comment: строку получаю и потом ее в цикле нужно будет записать в массив, правильно?

Comment: По идее потом эту строку как json читаете и делаете что нужно. Можно сделать проще, если либы использовать типа `Gson`

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно с gson это сделать, как раз сижу копаю информацию по этому вопросу. Но как всегда, конкретную задачу решить поначалу сложно для новичка

Comment: Кратко описать не могу - надо модель данных и прочие хитрости. Можете просто в цикле разобрать.